# Fill NA's for variables with singular unique grouped value after adding total row to grouped dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I would like to expand on the answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66137467/12215458 which adds a row to a data frame that is the total for grouped rows. I am looking for a way to fill in other grouped variables if they are the same in all rows of a given group, and leave the NA's if there are different values in each row of the grouping.

Please consider this example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df.in <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~fullsite,      ~sample, ~replicate, ~Count, ~analysis, ~percent_area,
    "D-01-06M-EA", "D-01-06m-E",        "a",   480L,      "5%",         3.783,
    "D-01-06M-EA", "D-01-06m-E",        "a",   576L,     "10%",         9.124,
    "D-01-06M-EA", "D-01-06m-E",        "a",   136L,   "total",        24.822,
    "D-03-02M-EA", "D-03-02m_E",        "a",   543L,      "5%",         3.422,
    "D-03-02M-EA", "D-03-02m_E",        "a",   728L,     "10%",         8.053,
    "D-03-02M-EA", "D-03-02m_E",        "a",   380L,   "total",        27.851
  )
df.in

df.tots <- df.in %>% 
  filter(analysis!='total') %>% 
  group_by(fullsite) %>% 
  summarise(Count=mean(Count))
df.tots

out <-   add_row(.data = df.in,
                  df.tots) %>% 
            arrange(fullsite) %>% 
            mutate(analysis=ifelse(is.na(analysis)==T,"meanof_5+10",analysis))
out
```

Note in my case I am summarizing only the values for the `5%` and `10%` analysis column for the summary data. I can easily add the required value for `analysis` as shown, but for the other columns which have NA's, and are all the same value (e.g. `sample` and `replicate` in this example) but **vary between groups**, I'd like to fill those as well. For the column `percent_area` I'm fine just leaving NA's since there isn't anything I could put here that would be useful.

I tried using `unique()` inside the call to `mutate()` hoping there would be some behavior to allow this inside a grouped data frame but this failed:

```
 out2 <-   add_row(.data = df.in,
                   df.tots) %>% 
  arrange(fullsite) %>% 
  mutate(analysis=ifelse(is.na(analysis)==T,"meanof_5+10",analysis),
         sample=ifelse(is.na(sample)==T,unique(sample),unique(sample))) %>% 
  arrange(fullsite)
out2
```

EDIT: Add expected outcome

```
out_expected <- out
out_expected$sample[is.na(out_expected$sample)==T&out_expected$fullsite=='D-01-06M-EA'] <- 'D-01-06M-E'
out_expected$sample[is.na(out_expected$sample)==T&out_expected$fullsite=='D-03-02M-EA'] <- 'D-03-02M-E'
out_expected$replicate[is.na(out_expected$replicate)==T&out_expected$fullsite=='D-01-06M-EA'] <- 'a'
out_expected$replicate[is.na(out_expected$replicate)==T&out_expected$fullsite=='D-03-02M-EA'] <- 'a'
out_expected
```

UPDATE:

It seems I can do this via multiple lines within a `mutate()` call, but for data where there are prohibitively large numbers of NA's I'd like to leave this question open for a while and see if anyone has suggestions.

```
add_row(.data = out,
        summ.dat) %>% 
  arrange(fullsite) %>% 
  mutate(analysis=ifelse(is.na(analysis), "meanof_5+10", analysis)) %>% 
  left_join(., counts_scuba %>% 
              rename(fullsite=site)) %>% 
  group_by(fullsite) %>% 
  mutate(sample=ifelse(is.na(sample)==T,substr(fullsite,1,10),sample),
         replicate=ifelse(is.na(replicate)==T,substr(fullsite,11,11),replicate)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sparked by a comment by @M-- here [Replace NA values with a specific condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75757376/replace-values-within-a-specific-condition-and-na/75757557#75757769)

it seems the best solution would be to use `tidyr::fill()`

```
out %>% fill(c(sample,replicate), .direction = 'down')
```