# Replace NA values with a specific condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame like this one:

```
first_column <- c(1,1,2,2,2)
second_column <- c(0.5,NA, 0.3,0.8,NA)
Third_column <- c(NA,0.8, 0.7,0.4, 0.7)

df <- data.frame (first_column,second_column,Third_column)
```

I would need to replace NA values for those participants with `first_column==1`, using information from the `second_column` to replace NA in the `Third_column` and using information from the `Third_column` to replace NA in the `second_column` so that I have a data set like this one:

```
first_column2 <- c(1,1,2,2,2)
second_column2 <- c(0.5,0.5, 0.3,0.8,NA)
Third_column2 <- c(0.8,0.8, 0.7,0.4, 0.7)

df2 <- data.frame (first_column2,second_column2,Third_column2)
```

I have tried using `ifelse` and\or `coalesce` functions but I cannot make  sense of it.

Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: Your desired data set does not match with your description. Shouldn't the second column be `c(0.5,0.8, 0.3,0.8,NA)` and the third column `c(0.5,0.8, 0.7,0.4, 0.7)`? Otherwise where are the missing values coming from?

Comment: @AllanCameron what they described is what you are showing in your comment, but their desired output is technically a `tidyr::fill(, .direction = "downup")`.

Answer (score 1):

This will create the dataframe requested:

first change the name of first and second dataframes.

```
first_column <- c(1,1,2,2,2)
second_column <- c(0.5,NA, 0.3,0.8,NA)
Third_column <- c(NA,0.8, 0.7,0.4, 0.7)

df <- data.frame (first_column,second_column,Third_column)
df

first_column2 <- c(1,1,2,2,2)
second_column2 <- c(0.5,0.5, 0.3,0.8,NA)
# second_column2 <- c(0.5,0.5, 0.3,0.8,NA)
Third_column2 <- c(0.8,0.8, 0.7,0.4, 0.7)
# Third_column2 <- c(0.5,0.8, 0.7,0.4, 0.7)
df2 <- data.frame (first_column2,second_column2,Third_column2)
df2
```

Here's the solution:

```
df %>% mutate(Third_column = ifelse(first_column==1 & is.na(Third_column),
                                       second_column, Third_column),
              second_column = ifelse(first_column==1 & is.na(second_column), 
                                       Third_column, second_column))
```

Comment: That works perfect! really elegant. Thank you so much and sorry for the mistake

Comment: If that's the answer you wanted you can make sure your question now reflects that and accept the answer by clicking the check mark. I'd urge you to examine @M-- answer below as well even if it doesn't fit here the `tidyr:fill()` function is one that I found useful for another use case which I had posted a question about and it may come in handy for you at another juncture!

Comment: You actually mentioned me and not the OP @JuanJMV. They won't get notified about a comment under your answer, unless you mention them. Thans for promoting my answer tho :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want values from `second_column` to fill `NA` in `Third_column` and vice versa, the following works. However, your desired output is different from what you described.

```r
library(dplyr)

cond_coalesce <- function(.x, .y, .z, val){
  require(dplyr)
  if_else(.x == val, coalesce(.y, .z), .y)
}

df1 %>% 
  mutate(second_column = 
           cond_coalesce(first_column, second_column, Third_column, 1),
         Third_column = 
           cond_coalesce(first_column, Third_column, second_column, 1))

#>   first_column second_column Third_column
#> 1            1           0.5          0.5
#> 2            1           0.8          0.8
#> 3            2           0.3          0.7
#> 4            2           0.8          0.4
#> 5            2            NA          0.7
```

If you are actually looking for your desired output, we can use `tidyr::fill`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(col2 = second_column, col3 = Third_column) %>% 
  fill(c(col2, col3), .direction = "downup") %>% 
  transmute(first_column, 
            second_column = if_else(first_column == 1, col2, second_column),
            Third_column = if_else(first_column == 1, col3, Third_column))

#>   first_column second_column Third_column
#> 1            1           0.5          0.8
#> 2            1           0.5          0.8
#> 3            2           0.3          0.7
#> 4            2           0.8          0.4
#> 5            2            NA          0.7
```

#### Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame (first_column = c(1,1,2,2,2),
                   second_column = c(0.5,NA, 0.3,0.8,NA),
                   Third_column = c(NA,0.8, 0.7,0.4, 0.7))
```