# Adding a total line for each sub group

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(school_type = c("nursery", "nursery", "nursery", "nursery", "primary", "primary", "primary", "primary"), 
                   staff_type = c("manager", "manager", "teacher", "teacher", "manager", "manager", "teacher", "teacher"),
                   age_group = c("20-30","30-40","20-30","30-40","20-30","30-40","20-30","30-40"), 
                   number_staff = c(40, 10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 20, 30), 
                   perc_staff = c(80, 20,40,60,80, 20,40,60))
```

| school_type | staff_type | age_group | number_staff | perc_staff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nursery | manager | 20-30 | 40 | 80 |
| nursery | manager | 30-40 | 10 | 20 |
| nursery | teacher | 20-30 | 20 | 40 |
| nursery | teacher | 30-40 | 30 | 60 |
| primary | manager | 20-30 | 40 | 80 |
| primary | manager | 30-40 | 10 | 20 |
| primary | teacher | 20-30 | 20 | 40 |
| primary | teacher | 30-40 | 30 | 60 |

This is the data frame I would like - showing a total for `school_type` and `staff_type` :

| school_type | staff_type | age_group | number_staff | perc_staff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nursery | manager | 20-30 | 40 | 80 |
| nursery | manager | 30-40 | 10 | 20 |
| nursery | manager | **Total** | 50 | 100 |
| nursery | teacher | 20-30 | 20 | 40 |
| nursery | teacher | 30-40 | 30 | 60 |
| nursery | teacher | **Total** | 50 | 100 |
| primary | manager | 20-30 | 40 | 80 |
| primary | manager | 30-40 | 10 | 20 |
| primary | manager | **Total** | 50 | 100 |
| primary | teacher | 20-30 | 20 | 40 |
| primary | teacher | 30-40 | 30 | 60 |
| primary | teacher | **Total** | 50 | 100 |

From this question: [Add 'total' row for each group in a column in df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66136737/add-total-row-for-each-group-in-a-column-in-df)

I got this code below, but that was when there was only one group type but I want a total for staff_type AND age_group:

```
data %>%
  dplyr::arrange(school_type) %>%
  split( .[,"???"] ) %>% # HERE - how do I split it by school_type AND staff_type??
  purrr::map_df(., janitor::adorn_totals)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You are missing some " in your example

Answer (score 0):

you could try :

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(school_type,staff_type) %>% 
summarize(age_group="Total",number_staff=sum(number_staff),perc_staff=sum(perc_staff) %>% 
bind_rows(data)
```

Comment: This also worked really well too - thanks for replying to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than one group to `split` using `c(...)`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  dplyr::arrange(school_type) %>%
  split( .[,c("school_type", "staff_type")]) %>%
  purrr::map_df(janitor::adorn_totals)

# school_type staff_type age_group number_staff perc_staff
#     nursery    manager     20-30           40         80
#     nursery    manager     30-40           10         20
#       Total          -         -           50        100
#     primary    manager     20-30           40         80
#     primary    manager     30-40           10         20
#       Total          -         -           50        100
#     nursery    teacher     20-30           20         40
#     nursery    teacher     30-40           30         60
#       Total          -         -           50        100
#     primary    teacher     20-30           20         40
#     primary    teacher     30-40           30         60
#       Total          -         -           50        100
```

You may also use `group_split` to stay in `dplyr`.

```
data %>%
  group_split(school_type, staff_type) %>%
  purrr::map_df(janitor::adorn_totals)
```

---

`adorn_totals` adds the text for total in the 1st column of the dataset. If you want to have it in `age_group` column then you need to move it to 1st column which can be done using `relocate`.

```
data %>%
  group_split(school_type, staff_type) %>%
  purrr::map_df(~.x %>% 
                  relocate(age_group, .before = 1) %>% 
                  janitor::adorn_totals(fill = NA, name = "All Ages")) %>%
  tidyr::fill(school_type, staff_type) %>%
  relocate(age_group, .after = 3)

# school_type staff_type age_group number_staff perc_staff
#     nursery    manager     20-30           40         80
#     nursery    manager     30-40           10         20
#     nursery    manager  All Ages           50        100
#     nursery    teacher     20-30           20         40
#     nursery    teacher     30-40           30         60
#     nursery    teacher  All Ages           50        100
#     primary    manager     20-30           40         80
#     primary    manager     30-40           10         20
#     primary    manager  All Ages           50        100
#     primary    teacher     20-30           20         40
#     primary    teacher     30-40           30         60
#     primary    teacher  All Ages           50        100
```

Comment: Just thought @Ronak shah - do you know if it is possible to make totals row show the school_type and the staff_type they are totalling? Because if the data frame is rearranged at a later date, it will not be clear what they are the total of......
For example for that first total row in your example:

nursery |manager |all ages |50 |100